# Proper way of aligning labes and buttons and TexBoxes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, layout, alignment

What is the proper way of aligning Label and button?

Bottom to bottom?

[image]

---

Text Bottom to text bottom?

[image]

The same question goes for TexBoxes and Buttons, TexBoxes and Labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Purple bar aligns line height of the label of each control. Via simply observing a couple of popular applications (i.e. Visual Studio), you can see that pretty much all controls are aligned according to their line heights (not bottoms). If you were bottom aligning controls, trying to change the size of a single control out of a series of bottom aligned controls would make them look seriously out of proportion.